# Angular: not getting reference of Form pristine/invalid status inside directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive "hasPermission" which is being used inside a Component. Function of this directive is to check permission if not have then disable the button but the moment i make any change to form fields like some text added it enables the button again and that is happening due to [disabled] property which looking for forms pristine/invalid status.

How can i manage this ?

I want to first check for permissions if that is there then only this  pristine/invalid comes into picture. Please guide.

If i get the status of this form's pristine/invalid inside directive I believe we can manage it but how to get it inside, i tried some solutions using DoCheck/Host etc none giving me Form reference inside Directive.

I don't want to use nativeElement (until some one says that is only way :))

[image]

Sample Code

```
   import {
    Directive,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    NgForm
} from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
    selector: '[haspermission]'
})
export class HaspermissionDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        ....
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.someService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(response => {
            this.store(response);
        });

    }

    store(data: IUser) {
        this.roles = JSON.parse(data.role);
        //.....doing some logic to calculate permissisons
        var hasPerm = this.roles.find(o => (o.RoleCode in permConfig.permission));
        if (!hasPerm) {
            this.element.nativeElement.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What u expect - angular or angularJs code? Also better  provide your current directive code

Comment: added sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use exportAs property on the Directive decorator.Which will expose  appHaspermission Directive instance.

> The exportAs takes the name under which the component instance is
>   exported in a template.

**appHaspermission.Directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHaspermission]',
  exportAs: 'hasPermission'
})
export class HaspermissionDirective implements OnInit {
  hasPermission = false;
  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hasPermission = true;
  }
}
```

Then create local variable on your button and assign in to exported hasPermission Directive so that you can access directive properties from template

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ngModel name="name" >
 <button #ref="hasPermission" appHaspermission  [disabled]="ref['hasPermission'] && (client.pristine || something else)" >Enable</button>
</form>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pebven

Comment: Awesome let me try this and then except it as an answer :)

Comment: Can you please have a look on my code above and suggest  if logic to calculate permission is in correct place ? i am using store

Comment: I think so and I am not good code reviewer. And The place where you put the store method is correct

Comment: Is #ref="hasPermission" necessary to be added to button?

Comment: yes so that you can get the haspermission directive instance

Comment: Ah got it this is reference variable. In some cases we use it directly with #